# Are filters available in JSR-168 portlets

Tags: portlet, portal, oc4j, wsrp

Is there any provision to implement filters for JSR-168 portlets similar to the servlet filters we normally configure in J2EE applications? Am basically new to using portlets and I am not sure if this question is already asked here. I searched and was not able to find an appropriate one.

My objective is to do a generic method call before the portlets are invoked each and every time. Am deploying the application in a OC4J-WSRP container. Is there any alternative approach to achieve this in case if there is no feature of filters?

Comment: The Portlet 1.0 spec (JSR-168) doesn't have a PortletFilter, but the 2.0 spec (JSR-286) does.

https://portlet-container.java.net/docs/jsr286.html#Portlet_Filters

I believe your container can host JSR-286 portlets.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, JSR-168 doesn't have portlet filters. However, as I understand WSRP, the communication between the consuming and producing servers is done via SOAP. This means you could have a filter that sits in between the two servers and manipulates the WSRP requests and responses as needed.

I don't know how difficult this would be since I'm not familiar with the specification or implementation details of WSRP and I don't know your current architecture if it would even be possible but it is an option that may fit your requirements.

Comment: Yes. I get your point but it wont help in case of my current requirement wherein I need to process certain bean objects which is not good to be processed at such an early stage.